# Using windows exported ".rdp" file from Ubuntu

Tags: remote-desktop, rdp, remmina

I got this ".rdp" remoteAPP file from work which enables me to run a specific application from the terminal server, I can open it easily using windows with a double click, are there any ways to open this kind of files from Ubuntu ?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can use [Remmina](https://remmina.org/how-to-install-remmina/), which is default application for remote desktop in Ubuntu from version 11.04.

From Remmina main menu select Tools -> Import and select your .rdp file. It will be imported and added to your saved connections in Remmina and you can use it anytime you start Remmina.

Comment: I couldn't find this menu on 13.04. But dragging and dropping the file into Remmina worked...

Comment: This application doesn't work with the more complex RDP connections.

Comment: Can I use Remmina to open MacInCloud connections in Ubuntu?  I just wanna double-click on the rdp file, just like on Windows.

Comment: The error I got in the GUI was just “Unable to establish a […]” without any explanation.  But opening the program in the terminal gave me this from stdout/stderr: `ERRCONNECT_NO_OR_MISSING_CREDENTIALS [0x0002001B]`.  Something to keep in mind.

Answer (score 7):

From the terminal this worked for me:

```
remmina -c Downloads/somemachine.rdp
```

The command line help says:

```
$ remmina  --help
...
-c, --connect=FILE          Connect to a .remmina file
```

Older versions of remmina don't understand the line `administrative session:i:1` in files produced by the azure portal, so you either need to upgrade remmina to a more recent version of comment out that line in the file (prefix with `#` works).

Answer (score 3):

Remmina works on Linux Mint 17.3 (Ubuntu 14.04 based)

however I could not get it to work directly with the .rdp file. Neither via import nor per double click.

what actually worked fine was:

opening the .rdp file with a texteditor. Copy pasting server name and gateway name to remmina.

edit: this also saves me from having to download the .rdp file, searching for it on my computer, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Drag and drop the rdp file in the Remmima inbuilt application. Select the connection and edit the details like password. Connect it. Should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I use KDE so I prefer krdc.
Here is a small script for running krdc with options from .rdp file.

```
#!/bin/bash
#
#
krdc `awk '
/^full address:s:/ { sub("full address:s:",""); sub("\015",""); host=$1; next}
/^username:s:/ { sub("username:s:",""); sub("\015",""); user=$1; next}
END { 
  printf "rdp://%s@%s\n", user, host 
}
' $1`
```

1. Copy above text to a file
2. Change file mode adding exec bit (chmod a+x file)
3. Run the file with your .rdp file as a parameter

I have only implemented basic parameters - user and hostname.
Feel free to implement others.
You may also use other rdp program - just change the name in the script.
The script provides parameter in a format `rdp://user@host`.

Answer (score 0):

To connect with Remmina from Ubuntu 20.04 I eventually found that I had to use two different usernames. The first is my email address, the second is a numeric id our institution also often use.

The email address is used as the "Remote Desktop Gateway username". The numeric id is the "Username" for the actual machine you finally connect to.

1. Either drag and drop your rdp file onto Remmina, or select "Import" from the hamburger menu towards the top-right.
2. A line of connection information should appear in Remmina. Right-click on it and choose "Edit".
3. Ensure the "Basic" tab is active.
4. Enter your "Username" (for me this is a numeric id).
5. Enter the "Domain".
6. Ensure the "Advanced" tab is active.
7. Enter your "Remote Desktop Gateway username" (for me this was my email address).
8. Enter your "Remote Desktop Gateway domain" (for me this was the same as at step 5, and needed in both these places).
9. Choose "Save" to return to the main Remmina window.
10. Either double-click on the line of connection information; or right-click it and select "Connect". A new pop-up window should soon appear, entitled "Enter RDP authentication credentials".
11. Enter your password.
12. Click OK.

That's it. The first option I wanted to change upon connecting was "Toggle Dynamic Resolution Update", which is on the left.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me in Linux Mint 20.3 Cinnamon:

1. Open Remmina.
2. Click *New Connection*.
3. Import the downloaded .RDP file (drop-down menu on the top right corner).
4. Fill in Username and Password.

That's it.
You only have to fiddle next with the resolution.
And it seems you will have to do this procedure each time you want to make a connection next time, i..e start a *New Connection* each time.