# 15.04 -- Open .RDP Files Automatically

Tags: rdp, remmina

Sorry if my question is a bit vague. I have a few .rdp connections that are saved onto my computer. Is there an RDP client I can install that will associate .rdp files to it, so I can connect to one of the RDP connections just by double-clicking it? I have tried to set this with Remmina, but when I double-click an RDP file, it simply opens Remina, it doens't actually connect.

Answer (score 4):

Remmina does not support opening RDP files. Instead you can open RDP files directly with xfreerdp, the actual RDP client that Remmina uses under the hood for RDP.

You have two options, both described in https://ubuntugenius.wordpress.com/2012/06/18/ubuntu-fix-add-program-to-list-of-applications-in-open-with-when-right-clicking-files-in-nautilus/

Option #1: create a mime-type file association:

Create file /usr/share/applications/xfreerdp.desktop with following contents:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=FreeRDP
Exec=xfreerdp %f
Terminal=true
Type=Application
MimeType=application/x-rdp
```

Now when you right-click the rdp file and go to options there will be an option to open it with "FreeRDP". The 'Terminal=true' option will open xfreerdp in the terminal (as it's a console application), where xfreerdp will ask for user credentials.

Option #2: use mimeopen:

Run mimeopen against your RDP file with the '-d' flag:

```
$ mimeopen -d <path to rdp file>
Please choose a default application for files of type text/plain

1) gnome  (gnome-usercreated-1)
2) LibreOffice Writer  (libreoffice-writer)
3) gedit  (org.gnome.gedit)
4) Vim  (vim)
5) Other...

use application #
```

Type the number corresponding to 'Other...'. In this case it's 5. You'll be asked to type the command:

```
use application #5
use command:
```

Because xfreerdp is a console app, you can't just type xfreerdp here. Instead pass xfreerdp as an argument to your terminal app, in my case gnome-terminal:

```
use command: gnome-terminal -x xfreerdp
```

The xfreerdp will then launch in a terminal window and will open the RDP file.

Comment: I can open rdp files with remmina either via 'import' in the gui, or with the command line option `-c` http://askubuntu.com/a/843906/79266

Comment: Thanks man, after six hours I finally got a working connection!