# How can I access hosted RDP on Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: rdp

I use my Ubuntu 15.10 laptop for work and need to access a remote computer.
Previously, I entered the IP, Domain and Password in Remmina and it just worked.

Now we have a "hosted" solution where I log into an account on a webpage and then download and open a .rdp file.

This works fine on Microsoft Remote Desktop but I cannot get it to work on Remmina or any other Ubuntu remote desktop client.

Any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this [Using windows exported ".rdp" file from Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/337441/using-windows-exported-rdp-file-from-ubuntu) is an answer for you. Remmina should import rdp file.

The other option, I can think of, is to write a program that would parse a rdp file that you download and create options for remmina which would work. As I recall rdp files are text files.

I would first investigate rdp file and try to make a connection with the settings from rdp file. To see if it works.

Comment: Thank you, Remmina imported it but couldn't connect. When I read the file, it was very long and full of security info which doesn't seem to be usable in remmina. I think for now I'll have to stick to Mac or Windows for this.